# How can i automate script executions in aws EC2 using go sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm building an app that manages multiple ec2 instances using the go sdk. I would like to run scripts on these instances in an automated way.

How can I achieve that ? I don't think os.command => ssh => raw script stored as string in code is the best practice. Is there any clean way to achieve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any clean way to achieve this ?

To bootstrap your instance, you would create a [UserData script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). The script runs only once, just after your instance is launched.

For other execution of commands remotely, you can use [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to run command on a single or multiple instances.

Comment: This SSM Run Command is the piece I was missing. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @rrrrr No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The way you suggest is actually valid and can work. I agree with you though, it wouldn't be my first choice either. I would either use the package `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` in the standard library or an external solution like   [github.com/appleboy/easyssh-proxy](https://github.com/appleboy/easyssh-proxy).

I would lean towards the default library but if you don't have a preference there then the [Scp](https://github.com/appleboy/easyssh-proxy/blob/e954c88dd7384602879776554482c701ef70f62c/easyssh.go#L377) function of the latter package might be especially of interest to you. You can find examples of this in the readme of the project.

> Secure copy protocol (SCP) is a means of securely transferring computer files between a local host and a remote host or between two remote hosts. It is based on the Secure Shell (SSH) protocol.

EDIT: After seeing [Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69097983/7258346), I think my answer is more the plain SSH answer, AWS independent. For the idiomatic answer for AWS please definitely look at his suggested solution!

Comment: Didn't know this ssh package existed, that's one less layer of dirtiness... Thanks